# Xcode storyboards and xibs for iPhone and iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, xcode-storyboard

I currently have an iPhone app thats uses xib's as the graphical interface.

We are planning to make an iPad app using the same code, but with a completely different graphical interface.

I really like storyboards because of the nice flow and overview and was thinking of using it only for the iPad, but I'm also considering not to because:

- Is it bad practice to have one for iPad but not for iPhone?
- The seque and push/present can probably be confusing?
- Having more developers in a storyboard can give merge nightmares?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is it bad practice to have one for iPad but not for iPhone?

If you continue to use only XIBs, do the same for both if its a universal app. It will be confusing for others who may work on your code. And you might end up with a lot of if else code.

> - The seque and push/present can probably be confusing?

Once you get used to it, its really a useful way of navigating between controllers. If you have any specific questions do point it out.

> - Having more developers in a storyboard can give merge nightmares?

Its just a XML document, any versioning system out there can handle merges pretty easily. As with any file if two or more developers have worked on same piece of code (in this case can be color change, layout change) then yes it will get conflicted. And developers should be in sync. If one dev is changing the whole structure of the controllers then yes it will be a nightmare. You need to wait and get the latest working copy and ammend your changes.

And you dont have to put all eggs in one basket. You can have multiple storyboards as well.

Comment: Thanks for quick response :-) The seque question was related to if having both storyboards and XIBs. I think I will keep it in XIB and maybe use storyboard for both iPhone and iPad in the future.